# FFmpeg remove black border on bottom of video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am pretty happy with this command. It takes three image inputs. Adds a fourth white background input that sets the size of the video and acts as a canvas.

The three inputs go through the `scale` filter then create three new outputs.

The new outputs are connected to the canvas, there is an overlay set (in the UI the user can position images on an x and y coordinate). Then three new outputs are created. I am structuring it this way so transitions are easier to manage.

Then on the final three outputs, I use the first one to transition into the second one. Then connect the third output to the transition.

I think I am not getting the 1080x1080 box because I have forgotten to place the transition outputs back onto the blank canvas, but I am not sure how to do that. Here is the command.

```
ffmpeg
    -i "0.jpg"
    -i "1.jpg"
    -i "2.jpg"
    -f lavfi
    -i color=c=white:s=1080x1080
    -filter_complex "

    // scale
    [0:v]scale=1330:1989[out1],
    [1:v]scale=1588:2381[out2],
    [2:v]scale=1144:1717[out3],

    // overlays
    [3:v][out1]overlay=-125:-454:enable='between(t,-0.5,5.5)'[out101],
    [3:v][out2]overlay=-340:-1093:enable='between(t,4.51,10.5)'[out102],
    [3:v][out3]overlay=-32:-13:enable='between(t,9.51,15)'[out103],

    // transitions
    [out101][out102]gltransition=duration=1:offset=4.51[vt0],
    [vt0][out103]gltransition=duration=1:offset=9.51[main]

    "
    -map "[main]"
    -ac 2
    -vcodec libx264
    -preset veryfast
    -crf 27
    -pix_fmt yuv420p
    -vb 20M
    -t 00:00:15
    out.mp4
```

Here is a link to the result https://storycreatoruploads2.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/f0eb5120-5511-11ea-8afc-05bd6ece194b you will see it's not sized correctly, there is a black square at the bottom.

Any way to get the image to fill the 1080x1080 square? Also, am I thinking about my command correctly?

Cheers

Comment: Does it still happen if you concat the overlaid result instead of using gltransition? (trim each image stream after scaling )

Comment: Here is the result https://storycreatoruploads2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/94758700-55a0-11ea-bf7a-0f3fe571c73f. I changed everything under // transitions to `[out101][out102][out103]concat=n=3[main]` not sure if that is correct. I am still learning FFmpeg, maybe I have the output streams mixed up. You can see in the rendered video it starts off ok for 0-5 seconds then cuts out on the next output. It did solve the black box though!

Comment: So, it looks like an issue with gltransition. Raise an issue with its author at https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-gl-transition/issues

Comment: Cool will do. We're actually friends, I think it's because the images need to be cropped at 1080x1080. I'll test that, then I'll ask him. Do you have any idea why when I concatenate the videos some of the outputs are white backgrounds? Similar thing happens with `[out101][out102]gltransition=duration=1:offset=4.5[vt0],
[vt0][out103]gltransition=duration=1:offset=9.5[vt104],
[out104][vt104]overlay[main]`. I can ask this in a new thread. Just wondering if I am missing something simple. You're the best! Thanks